# AcroForm TextBox fields baseline misalignment using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp (5.5.6) to fillup some Acroform and I noticed some strange behaviour:

1. in some cases if I fill the AcroForm iTextSharp  placing text in a TextBox field and then I flatten the form the text of the field is 'rendered' at a different distance from the baseline of the TextBox if compared with the same AcroForm filled trough Acrobat Reader;
2. If I fill a checkbox with the matching value (to 'check' it) and then I flatten the form the resulting PDF is rendered with a different 'check' symbol.

This's the code I'm using to fill and flatten the AcroForm :

```
    private string fill_form(string output_file)
    {
        using (PdfReader _pdfReader = new PdfReader(FormPath))
        {
            using (PdfStamper _pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(_pdfReader, new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;

                foreach (var _field in _pdfStamper.AcroFields.Fields)
                    foreach (TemplateField _spField in _lstFields)
                    {
                        if (_field.Key.Equals(_spField.Name))
                        {
                            switch (_spField.Type )
                            {
                                case TemplateFieldType.Text:
                                    _pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key, _spField.Value);
                                    break;

                                case TemplateFieldType.Checkbox:
                                    if (_spField.Value == _spField.OnValue)
                                        _pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key, _spField.OnValue);
                                    else
                                        _pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key, _spField.OffValue);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                _pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            }
        }

        return output_file;
    }
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Which iTextSharp version do you use? I remember that once upon a time there had been issues like that but they meanwhile have been resolved.

Comment: Hhmmm. Ok, which podge can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You can use the code you can read there. I cannot provide you the AcroForm since it's something I cannot freely deliver anyway they have been created and optimized with Adobe Acrobat (so I think they should be quite 'compliant' to PDF 'standards').
_lstFields is just a list that contains the stored values I would like to fill the form with but you can use static values.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with some freely available PDF. If yes, please share it. If no, chances are there is something fishy about your PDF and nothing can be done without it. So either way, please supply a PDF to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can create a PDF form trough OpenOffice and try it...